# I am looking for a substitution for milk in risotto

Tags: substitutions

I have Knorr four cheese risotto mix. It calls for 1/2 cup of milk. I dont have any. Can I use fat free sour cream instead?

Answer (score 1):

So the milk does 3 things: 1 adds dairy flavor, 2 adds liquid, and 3 adds fat. Maybe if you mixed 2/3 fat free sour cream with water until it was a consistent texture, you might have a kinda-approximation. It'll be thicker, perhaps granier, and tangier. Personally I'd just add 3/4 that amount of water and 1/4 that amount of butter.

Comment: Welcome! Why those percentages? What about the dairy flavor you mention?

Comment: The sour cream thing is a shot in the dark, but I'm pretty confident that what you'd end up with wouldn't be 'terrible.' The butter/water thing just approximates the amount of fat and liquid you'd get with a slightly richer half and half, or a slightly lighter light cream. You'd lose some flavor by using water instead of milk, but you'd make up for some by using the butter. Mostly, it's just gut instinct from my time troubleshooting in professional kitchens and culinary schoool.